# Indian driving license in Indonesia?

Tags: indian-citizens, driving-licenses, indonesia

I have a driving license issued by the Indian government (I'm citizen of India). How can i use it in Indonesia? Not for driving taxi but for regular use as a visitor. Do I need to apply for new license in Indonesia?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes**, as a tourist [you can use your own license](http://indonesia.angloinfo.com/transport/driving-licences/), but you will also need to get an International Driving Permit (IDP).  In India you can get this from your local RTO office, procedures will vary slightly but [here's the requirements for Karnataka](http://rto.kar.nic.in/IDP-PROCcss.html).

Comment: Does same goes with 2 Wheeler also? I mean, for IDP one of the requirement is to show "Visa" but for Indians, Indonesia has free visa so I won't be having visa while applying for IDP